# More elegant way of checking if a RadioButton is checked in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, radio-button

I'm working on a Winforms app and I have 5 radio buttons. I need to know which one is checked. Is there a better/more compact way of doing this in C#?

For now I have this:

```
if (rbtnArgent.Checked)
    return "Silver";
else if (rbtnBleuF.Checked)
    return "Dark Blue";
else if (rbtnBleuP.Checked)
    return "Light Blue";
else if (rbtnJaune.Checked)
    return "Yellow";
else
    return "Pink";
```

It's working but maybe i will need to add more radio buttons to my form in the future...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider setting the Tag property to a color than use the following code to get the checked RadioButton.

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Descendants<T>(this Control control) where T : class
    {
        foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
        {
            if (child is T thisControl)
                yield return thisControl;
            if (!child.HasChildren) continue;
            foreach (T descendant in Descendants<T>(child))
                yield return descendant;
        }
    }
    public static RadioButton RadioButtonChecked(this Control control, bool @checked = true)
        => control.Descendants<RadioButton>().ToList()
            .FirstOrDefault((radioButton) => radioButton.Checked == @checked);

    public static string GetColor(this RadioButton radioButton) 
        => radioButton.Tag.ToString();
}
```

Usage in a Button Click event

```
var rb = this.RadioButtonChecked();

if (rb is not null)
{
    MessageBox.Show(rb.GetColor());
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Make a selection");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out Microsoft's [RadioButton docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.radiobutton). Their solution is to handle the `RadioButtons` being clicked in events, and keep track of the currently active one.

That would give you:

```
// Reference to current radiobutton
RadioButton selectedrb;

// Register event handlers for all your radio buttons
rbtnArgent.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(radioButton_CheckedChanged);
rbtnBleuF.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(radioButton_CheckedChanged);
// ... (You could also do this in a loop if you were to have a lot of radiobuttons)

void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    RadioButton rb = sender as RadioButton;

    if (rb == null) {
        MessageBox.Show("Sender is not a RadioButton");
        return;
    }

    // Ensure that the RadioButton.Checked property
    // changed to true.
    if (rb.Checked) {
        // Keep track of the selected RadioButton by saving a reference to it
        selectedrb = rb;
    }
}

// When you want to check the radiobutton, just compare against the value of selectedrb
```